# How to save a paperclip attachement from the params hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, paperclip, parameters

I'm trying to create an instance of my `CompanyLogo` model if the hash `params[:vacancy]['companies']['company_logo']` is pressent. I'm attempting to do this:

```
l = CompanyLogo.new( :company_logo => params[:vacancy]['companies']['company_logo'].tempfile.path )
```

but that gives me

```
CompanyLogo(#70304040244500) expected, got ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile(#70304015073440)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you paste your full params hash

Comment: what does your model look like in regards to paperclip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your CompanyLogo has_attached :logo,and you are saving file manually then simply `company_logo_object.logo = File.new(actual_path)` and 
 `company_logo_object.save` solve your purpose

Answer (score 1):

Try saving the logo first (tested in Rails 3.2.2 using Paperclip)

> (logo = CompanyLogo.new(:image => params[:image])).save
>
> company_object.update_attributes(logo: logo)

Comment: I already accepted the other answer, your method works too, I think, although `.update_attributes(logo: logo)` looks strange to me.